# Trying to send a string of words in a particular format

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets, dictionary

Right now I'm dealing with socket.io on objective -c and I'm working on sending event requests. I'm working with pkyeck socket.io api and to send an event, they way he set it up you put the args value in a dictionary with which is handled in the sentevent function with takes the dictionary of variables you sent and matches it with the args key. So if I follow that pattern, the event I send to the socket.io server looks like this.

```
{"args":[{"username":"yeah", "id":"2"}],"name":"login"}
```

However for my server to properly handle a socket.io call the call needs to look like this.

```
{"args":["yeah","2"],"name":"login"}
```

But I'm not able to send the variables in such a way for the dictionary to set it up like that. If I use a NSArray the request is sent as such.

```
{"args":[["yeah","2"]}],"name":"login"}
```

If I send an appended string it looks like this.

```
{"args":[{"'yeah','2'"}],"name":"login"}
```

This is what I have done so far

```
- (void) socketIO:(SocketIO *)socket onMessage:(NSString *)status{
NSLog(@"Current status %@", status);
if([status isEqualToString:@"ready"]){
    SocketIOCallback cb = ^(id argsData) {
        NSDictionary *response = argsData;
        // do something with response
        NSLog(@"ack arrived: %@", response);

        // test forced disconnect
        //[socketIO disconnectForced];
    };
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [dict setObject:@"Yeah" forKey:@"username"];
    [dict setObject:@"eqe74squbaah9eqvk7bok3rh09" forKey:@"session"];
    [dict setObject:userid forKey:@"user_id"];
    NSMutableArray *arr=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Yeah", @"eqe74squbaah9eqvk7bok3rh09", userid, nil];

    NSString *eventName=@"'Yeah',";
    eventName=[eventName stringByAppendingString:@"'eqe74squbaah9eqvk7bok3rh09',"];
    eventName=[eventName stringByAppendingString:@"'"];
    eventName=[eventName stringByAppendingString:userid];
    eventName=[eventName stringByAppendingString:@"'"];

   // NSLog(@"This is the string to be sent %@",eventName);

    [socketIO sendEvent:@"login" withData:eventName andAcknowledge:cb];
    [socketIO sendEvent:@"subscribe" withData:@"47058" andAcknowledge:cb];
}
```

This is the method that sends the socket.io event request.

```
- (void) sendEvent:(NSString *)eventName withData:(id)data andAcknowledge:(SocketIOCallback)function
{
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:eventName forKey:@"name"];

    // do not require arguments
    if (data != nil) {
        [dict setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:data] forKey:@"args"];
    }

    SocketIOPacket *packet = [[SocketIOPacket alloc] initWithType:@"event"];
    packet.data = [SocketIOJSONSerialization JSONStringFromObject:dict error:nil];
    packet.pId = [self addAcknowledge:function];
    if (function) {
        packet.ack = @"data";
    }
    [self send:packet];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to my mind would be to make the string entirely yourself with something like:

```
NSString Query = [stringFormatWithString "{\"args\":[{\"username\":\"%@\",     \"id\":\"%@\"}],\"name\":\"%@\"}", usernameVariable,idVariable,nameVariable];
```